# How to combine robot odometry with RGBD SLAM algorithm for mapping?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbd6dslam, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use rgbdslam package for building a 3d map and it is successful. Now, I would like to combine the robot odometry with this algorithm for mapping. Is there any possiblity to do this?

If possible, how to do it?

Thanks in advance for the reply.

---

updated:

Now, I defined the transformation between frames 'odom' and 'openni_camera'. Also, the '/tf' has 'odom' as its initial frame and it is subscribed by package 'rgbdslam'. Even though, I have a doubt that whether 'rgbdslam' will consider it for mapping or not?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42947/how-to-combine-robot-odometry-with-rgbd-slam-algorithm-for-mapping-?/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Later, I came to know that we have to set the following parameter in launch file - "rgbdslam_sample_config.launch"

param name="config/odom_frame_name"
value="fixed_frame_to_odometry"

---

Originally posted by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) with karma: 171 on 2012-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0